# Jenkins_"Please wait while Jenkins is restarting" , quite a persistent one

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am getting the "Please wait while Jenkins is restarting" issue , I have restarted the Jenkins service but it still isn't working , I tried to install a plugin yesterday and since then it's showing me that message.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What does the logs say? /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log

Comment: It says this: "java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind" and "SEVERE: Container startup failed
java.io.IOException: Failed to start Jetty"  also this one too: "SEVERE: Failed to initialize Jenkins
hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad: java.lang.InterruptedException"  If it makes any sense to you then please do let me know.......Thank you.

Comment: Are you starting the slave on Unix or windows? It means that another application is already using the port configured for Jenkins. My guess is that your previous Jenkins instance was not stopped properly. So now you need to kill the application that is holding your port. And restart.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing which will work almost every time is:

- Login to the (windows) server where Jenkins is hosted.
- Open CMD Prompt as administrator.
- Go to path where jenkins.exe file is placed.
- Enter command: *jenkins.exe* *stop* and then *jenkins.exe start*

For Linux server, kill the process and restart again.